# Cucumber js 1/Webdriver.io - embedding screenshot to step instead of After hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am using the following for running my tests:

1. Webdriver.io 4.2
2. Cucumber.js 1.1.3
3. multiple-cucumber-html-reporter of reports

I am embedding the screenshots in the After hook and they appear in the report in After hook, but the assertion error is seen in the failed step. I want to embed the screenshot in the step itself when the test fails instead of in the After hook.

As per multiple-cucumber-html-reporter documentation it can show anything that's attached to the cucumber json file.

Can someone help me in embedding the screenshot to the failed step, please?

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 0):

*The check if your test failed or not and the actual screenshot embedding currently resides in your `After` hook.
So it's saved as an attachment in your `After` hook*

If you want to move this check to every step indivually, I guess you'd need to wrap the cucumber step definitions or add the screenshot in every step.

How, depends a bit if you're working with callbacks or promises. Different approaches/level of wrappings are possible (like wrapping `cucumber.When` itself or just the callback)

Promise example for a single step:

```
When( "cucumber expression", function()
{
   return myTestPromise
      .catch(takeScreenshot)
}
```

OR:
post-process your .json output, to move embedding from After to the failing step.
(warning: fragility ahead)

Either way, its extra/non-default code. You have to ask yourself if its worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wouldn't want to do a post process on Json file, that can have unexpected results. I will take the wrapping and let you know.